# Unexpected token '<' when trying to load my webcomponent in html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

so im trying to create a react webcomponent. I wrap it and on VSCode looks fine, but when I'm trying to load it, it gives me the error: Unexpected token '<' on the line:

`ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, mountPoint);`

Does anyone know why and how to fix it? thanks

This is my WebComponent:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Counter from './counter';

class CounterWC extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {

        // Create a ShadowDOM
        const root = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

        // Create a mount element
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('div');

        root.appendChild(mountPoint);

        // You can directly use shadow root as a mount point
        ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, mountPoint);
    }
}

customElements.define('counter-wc', CounterWC)
```

And this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-9" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>React webcomponent:</h1>
    <counter-wc></counter-wc>
    <script type="module" src="./counterWC.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is JSX code, it has to be transpiled to js first.

Comment: I agree with @tkausl. You cannot import a file with JSX into an html file. You can check the basics of React in their official page here https://beta.reactjs.org/learn.

Comment: I dont understand, i made my both components on js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: comments

The fact that you name your file *.js doesn't mean it **is** JavaScript

`ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, mountPoint);` is JSX, **not** JavaScript, it needs to be converted in a *Build* step to JavaScript.

Or do not use React at all:

```js
class CounterWC extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super() 
     .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
     .append(this.div = document.createElement('div'));
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.div.innerHTML = `Am I a counter?`;
  }
}

customElements.define('counter-wc', CounterWC);
```

```html
<counter-wc></counter-wc>
```